# Identity Server, website hosting, octopus

Tags: web-services, identity, identityserver3, openid-connect, octopus-deploy

I have recently inherited a Web API development that exposes key endpoints to a company that is hosting and running our website.
We use Octopus to deploy the API to our webserver. 
I have duplicated the API and added the appropriate configuration variable to Octopus and deployed it to a secondary webserver (as a development API) for our 3rd party to use.
We are using identity server along with OpenID connect for authentication.
This has built and deployed however authentication is failing.

I know this is a vague description, but I am looking for pointers for an analysis path.

I have compared the logs of the current Api and the test Api and results are the same. (Stating authentication is successful)

Comment: It's impossible to help without you getting more in to detail, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not really enough information to properly answer this question - but I would start by:

1) Checking all the log files you can find for a more detailed exception message. (application logs, IIS logs, event log)

2) Try to narrow down the issue. Does authentication fail for everyone/all the time? Or is this an issue intermittent? Does it work locally? For certain providers only?

3) Slowly start making the new website look like the old website. Comparing web.config files, copy/pasting the old website code onto the new server etc.

4) Check or restore old service accounts, firewall settings, database values, urls etc.

If all else fails - bring everything back to a working state and start changing one thing at a time until you have a little more experience with the application.

Comment: Many thanks... the analysis path and next steps are a start. Once I finally get to the bottom of the issue, I will post a detailed explanation of the issue and fix :-)

Comment: No problem.. :)

Comment: Was this an acceptable answer or were looking for more details??